# Number to Time Oracle

Tags: oracle

Just wondering if I might be able to get some help. I'm trying to convert the following 42499 into a time field in Oracle. The field is currently a varchar2

Thank you

I've tried to_number(to_date(transactiontime, 'hh24ss'))

ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
01850. 00000 -  "hour must be between 0 and 23"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: What is `42499` supposed to represent (i.e. what is the desired result of the conversion)?

Comment: `'hh24ss'` is an odd format model for `to_date()`, since it specifies only time components, not any date components.  And `to_date()` is an odd conversion to perform if you want a time.  Do you maybe want a `TIMESTAMP` instead?  Or an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't have a time-only data type, but you can convert to a date, as you are attempting; if the value you have represents a time as the number of seconds past midnight then you can use the `sssss` [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3):

```
to_date(to_number(transactiontime), 'sssss')
```

Your client will probably be configured to show just the date, or the full date time, so you might see `01-MAY-23` or `2023-05-01 11:48:19` or something else. (If you don't specify any date elements it defaults to the first day of the current month.) You can convert the date back to a string with `to_char()`:

```
to_char(to_date(to_number(transactiontime), 'sssss'), 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

which will give `11:48:19`.

You can also convert your number to an interval data type with:

```
numtodsinterval(to_number(transactiontime), 'SECOND')
```

or

```
to_number(transactiontime) * interval '1' second
```

which both give `+000000000 11:48:19.000000000`.

You can't format that directly, but you could cut out the bit you want with:

```
substr(to_number(transactiontime) * interval '1' second, 12, 8)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cEeBBkPR)

Or you could add that interval to a fixed date (at midnight), such as a date literal like `date '1970-01-01'; or - if you are for some reason storing your transaction date and time as two separate fields (which is rarely, if ever, sensible) - to *that* date. And you can then format the combined value however you want.

Answer (score -1):

For converting a number to date to simply need TO_DATE() function that will automatically convert it and also you can provide parameters for the output which you want.

Here is the complete guide of formats and syntax information [Oracle Dates](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

You can use this query that will work for you. "Dual" is basically used when you want a dummy table(row/column) dataset and systems time etc.

```
Select TO_DATE('42499', 'HH:MM:SS') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Your query will get the same ORA-01850 error as the original 'hh24ss' version.

Comment: You have not understood how `TO_DATE` works. The format specifies what the string looks like. You tell the DBMS that it starts with the hour, then a colon, then minutes, then a colon, then seconds. There is no colon in '42499', so the format you have given the DBMS is inadequate.